# Quantum Analogue of the Absolute Elsewhere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

The absolute elsewhere in SR describes events that lie outside the lightcone structure. Is there an analogue in quantum mechanics (however construed)?

Answer (score 0):

Questions involving this are solved simply by placing quantum particles in a *space-time diagram* and drawing the appropriate light cones. An excellent example can be had in Feynmann's Dirac Memorial Lecture, where he puts quantum particles in a space-time diagram and derives the existence of antiparticles in a straightforward way.